# Как захватить поток с v4l2loopback в программе?

Tags: linux

Я установил v4l2lb и у меня появился /dev/video0 я транслирую на него свой экран через ffmpeg но когда запускаю cheese не нахожу там свой вывод. Где моя ошибка?

Comment: как именно запускаешь/настраиваешь драйвер/ffmpeg?

Comment: @Fat-Zer  ffmpeg -f x11grab -s 1280x800 -r 30 -i :0.0 -vcodec qtrle /dev/video0

Comment: почти наверняка драйвер не знает, как декодировать `qtrle` и ему нужно подавать на вход сырые данные в определённом формате... сейчас сказать не смогу в каком, но может быть вечером поэксперементирую...

Comment: @Fat-Zer я не уверен что  подавал qtrle я не знаю точно команду но помню ffmpeg и /dev/video0 в конце проблема в том что ни 1 программа не видит виртуальную камеру v4l2

Comment: Я хочу добится такого же результата как AlterCam на Windows тоесть захватывать окно,эркан,файл через фф и передовать в в4л2 а оттуда забирать как с веб камеры любыми программами